# Package "sun.org.mozilla.javascript.internal" not found in rt.jar for jdk1.8.0_131

Tags: java, java-8

I'm upgrading my app from jdk 7 to jdk8, but found that Package "**sun.org.mozilla.javascript.internal**" no longer exist in rt.jar, is there a alternative jar i can import to resolve the problem? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I try to use rhino.jar instead, and it works!